# Not Receiving iOS VoIP Notifications with In House Provisioning Profile

Tags: ios, xcode, notifications, voip, provisioning-profile

I'm trying to implement VoIP notifications into my app following this tutorial: http://pierremarcairoldi.com/ios-8-voip-notifications/

I'm making an app that will be distributed internally with an Apple Developer Enterprise program (in-house deployment).

I followed every step of the tutorial and I've tried to send notifications using a development provisioning profile. All works normally and I'm able to receive those notifications.

The problem is when I switch to an In-house provisioning profile. The app finishes to register the VoIP token with the server correctly, but when I send notifications through `houston` with the new token nothing happens, including the fact that the app doesn't enter in the `pushRegistry:didReceiveIncomingPushWithPayload:forType:` method.

Are there any limitations of this feature when using in-house profiles or am I doing something wrong?

Thanks in advance!